# refer to specific class in wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I want to refer to specific class in navigation of my website by click on hyperlink , this class in the same page of my navigation, in normal situation I think it's possible by

```
<a href = ".contact_us">Contact Us</a>
```

but in WordPress , I'm using Js Composer , and I have no idea about where class of contact_us.

[image]
how to find this class?

Comment: What? It dosen't matters wherever your class is , if it's in same document that is being loaded , then it'll navigate to it.

Comment: @AbhinavGauniyal 
for example my url is afn.com , and class name is contact_us_title , when I used to navigate to this class ,it's not found. (http://afn.com/contact_us_title)

Comment: that is definitely not a class but another webpage.

Comment: @AbhinavGauniyal actually the main fail in "wordpress/wp-content/themes/bizflare.1.0.14/bizflare/index" and js composer plugin in above link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use ID for that  and navigate to it :

```
<a href = "#contact_us">Contact Us</a>
.
.
.
.
<div id="contact_us"> <a name="contact_us"/>
```